# Cannot access child nodes under ToolBar in HTMLEditor

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm using JavaFX 8.
I want to use HTMLEditor with hiding some default controls eg. indent/outdent, bullets and numbers.
To do this, I tried to access child nodes by getItems and getChildren methods, so that I could remove them from the list.

```
 HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();
 HTMLEditorSkin skin = (HTMLEditorSkin)editor.getSkin();
 GridPane gp = (GridPane)skin.getChildren().get(0);
 ToolBar tb = (ToolBar)gp.getChildren().get(0);
 System.out.println(tb.getItems());
 System.out.println(tb.getChildrenUnmodifiable());
```

I read source code of HTMLEditorSkin and there must be controls under tb, but the code above shows only two empty lists like "[]".

I know this should not be the best way, but I'd appreciate if anyone could help me.

Comment: When are you executing this code? You likely need to wait until a layout has been performed for this to succeed. Maybe try calling `applyCss()` and then `layout()` on the parent of the `editor` before you execute this (if you're not doing so already).

Comment: @James_D I executed them in initialize method. I didn't know well yet the sequence of initialization of nodes and how nodes are loaded , but I'll learn it with your hint. Thank you.

Comment: @James_D I still haven't learned the initialization yet, but apparently it's not problem when to execute, as when I execute them after #initialize I still get same result.

Answer (score 0):

Call these methods
htmlEditor.applyCss();
htmlEditor.layout();

before you use: (ToolBar) bottomToolBar).getItems()